# Pushing form values to an array. (React)

Tags: reactjs

I'm having some trouble pushing the values from my `form` to an array that I'm mapping on screen.

```
const ForumTopic = [
  {
    title: "First Post",
    messages: "test",
    author: "Dagger",
    count: 1,
    date: "02/16",
  },
];

const [topic, setTopic] = useState(ForumTopic);
```

Storing ForumTopic in state so I can add entries and display on screen after I click the submit button below.

```
  const addTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTopic([...topic, e.target.value]);
  };

  <form onSubmit={addTopic}>
          Create a topic title
          <label htmlFor="title">
            <input id="title"></input>
          </label>
          Write your message
          <label htmlFor="message">
            <textarea id="message"></textarea>
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="author">
            <input id="author" defaultValue="Dagger" hidden></input>
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="count">
            <input id="count" defaultValue="1" hidden></input>
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="date">
            <input id="date" defaultValue="02/16/2023" hidden></input>
          </label>
          <button type="submit">
            Post New Message
          </button>
        </form>
```

That's my code and form. The code is meant to push the values from each label in the form to create a new object inside the `topic` array. I want everything stored in a new object with the `id` of each label to match the names of each object (title, author, date, etc) but for some reason all I'm getting are undefined errors.

Comment: onSubmit={() => addTopic(e)} .. can you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is like this.

You need to obtain the value you are getting with an onChange in the input.

LINK to the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8r9f8l?file=src%2FApp.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ForumTopic = [
  {
    title: 'First Post',
    messages: 'test',
    author: 'Dagger',
    count: 1,
    date: '02/16',
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [topic, setTopic] = useState(ForumTopic);
  const [inputObj, setInputObj] = useState({
    title: '',
    messages: '',
    author: 'Dagger',
    count: 1,
    date: '02/16',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputObj((curr) => ({
      ...curr,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const addTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTopic([...topic, inputObj]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={addTopic}>
        <label htmlFor="title">
          Create a topic title
          <input
            id="title"
            name="title"
            value={inputObj.title}
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="message">
          Write your message
          <textarea
            id="message"
            name="messages"
            value={inputObj.messages}
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></textarea>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="author">
          <input id="author" name="author" defaultValue="Dagger" hidden></input>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="count">
          <input id="count" name="count" defaultValue="1" hidden></input>
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="date">
          <input id="date" name="date" defaultValue="02/16/2023" hidden></input>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Post New Message</button>
      </form>
      {topic.map((item) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
            <p>{item.messages}</p>
            <p>{item.author}</p>
            <p>{item.count}</p>
            <p>{item.date}</p>
            <span>------------</span>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey I've update it so you do not have to create every input state

Comment: That does look a lot cleaner. Thank you so much! Your first solution allowed me to easily change the values of both the topic and post to an empty string but I'm unable to do that now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on your addTopic function:
e.target.value are always undefined

to access the data you have to do:

```
const addTopic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const myData = {
        title: e.target.title.value,
        message: e.target.message.value
    }
    
    setTopic(prev => [...prev, myData])        

}
```